# Log4j has stopped working after switch the server(Grals 2.5.1 project)

Tags: java, grails, log4j, tomcat7

`Log4j` has stopped sending mail and printing info log while deploying the war in new servers. It was working fine before while deploying the war in old severs. I have attached the log4j configuration here with. Please suggest the possible solutions. Also I have seen some `javax` class not found error while deploying the war. Note: it is working when we run the project by grails run-app command. And also it start working in war if we remove the mail send part from configuration.

I am using **tomcat server**.

```
log4j = {

    appenders {
        if (grails.util.Environment.current.equals(grails.util.Environment.DEVELOPMENT)){

            System.setProperty 'mail.debug', 'false'
            System.setProperty 'mail.smtp.protocol', 'smtp'
            System.setProperty 'mail.smtp.auth', 'true'
            System.setProperty 'mail.smtp.starttls.enable', 'true'
            System.setProperty 'mail.smtp.starttls.required', 'true'
            def patternLayout = new org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout()
            def mailAppender  = new org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender()

            patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss} %C %m%n")
            mailAppender.setSMTPPort(587)
            mailAppender.setFrom("")
            mailAppender.setTo("")
            mailAppender.setSubject("Log4j error generated for Care Manager LOCAL")
            mailAppender.setSMTPHost("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
            mailAppender.setLayout(patternLayout)
            mailAppender.setSMTPDebug(false)
            mailAppender.setSMTPUsername("")
            mailAppender.setSMTPPassword("")
            mailAppender.setThreshold(org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR)
            appender name:'mail', mailAppender
        }
    }

    root {
        error 'mail','stdout'
        error 'stdout'
        debug 'stdout'

    }

    //  for spring security
    //debug   'grails.plugins.springsecurity'
    //debug   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity'
    //debug   'org.springframework.security'
    // debug   'org.jasig.cas.client'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
            'org.apache'
    debug 'org.jasig.cas.client.proxy',
          'org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.Cas20ProxyRetriever'            


    info  additivity: false,
            stdout:[ 'grails.app.controllers']
    debug  additivity: false,
            stdout:[ 'grails.app.controllers']
}
```

Comment: Solution? Figure out the difference between the old servers and the new servers. If your code hasn't changed, you shouldn't be looking at your code until you understand the differences between the environments your code is running in.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion it is working after run the project in the exact replica of old servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ¿why you have System configuration parameters inside Log4J's appenders? At least, that should be in the BootStrap.

Now, when you create a new server your first need to install and configure all its dependencies in order to Grails to run. Check the Java version installed, Grails version, PATH environment variable, DNS configuration and permissions, (specially proxies configurations).

If the code has not changed and its not working, it's definitely an environmental issue.

Comment: Yes there was an environment setup issue. It is working after make exact replica of old server. Thank you for your kind suggestion.